# PHP While loop with A HREF

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, href

I would like to know how to solve this issue with a while loop and a href link inside
instead of using submit button.

When I click the link I'm echoing out everything that is in loop but I want to only 
echo out the id which I have clicked on.

Here is my little code:

```
<?php 
while( $profile_images_not_approved_view = mysql_fetch_array($profile_images_not_approved)) {

        if (isset($_GET['approve']) == $profile_images_not_approved_view['id']) 
        {
            echo "hello id";
            echo $profile_images_not_approved_view['id'];   
        }
?>


<td class="center">
<a href="?p=testme&approve";?>" name="<?php echo $profile_images_not_approved_view['id'];?>" class="button small grey tooltip"></a>
</td>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Your code is weird. Look over the <a href line and try to correct it - I can't understand what that should mean.

Comment: You aren't passing any id in the url

Comment: an href will resubmit the page, the id's which you checked will be lost. Use a Submit button, Check the values in JS, let the JS pass on the variables back, or use AJAX

Comment: So it's not possible to use the an href istead of submit button?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
    while( $profile_images_not_approved_view = mysql_fetch_array($profile_images_not_approved)) {

            if (isset($_GET['approve']) && $_GET['approve'] == $profile_images_not_approved_view['id']) 
            {
                echo "hello id";
                echo $profile_images_not_approved_view['id'];   
            }
    ?>


    <td class="center">
        <a href="?p=testme&approve=<?php echo $profile_images_not_approved_view['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo $profile_images_not_approved_view['id'];?>" class="button small grey tooltip"> </a>
    </td>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You are right. I have changed it, and it should work now.